# Prevent multiselect from checking last value from

Tags: jquery

I'd like to implement the multiple select element that would prevent users from checking all of the values from the list (all -1 is acceptable). I've written some jquery code, but I don't know what is wrong with it. Any help?
HTML:

```
<select class='custom-header' id='custom-header' multiple='multiple' name="my-select">
     <option class="test" value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
     <option  class="test" value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
     <option class="test" value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
     <option class="test" value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
     <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var userChoice = $(".test");
$.each(userChoice, function(index,value){
   if(index = userChoice.length -1){
      alert("The last was clicked.");
   }
});
```

Comment: are you want to prevent selection of last one or you want to select total -1 ???????/

Comment: 1,2,3..or total -1 is possible. Minimum one choice has to stay unchecked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ybv6sq6/

Comment: be careful with your selected answer for example if you select first 4 option and then  deselect  2 option after that when you again try to select that two option it will clear all option and you have to select all again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will prevent you from selecting all options:

```
$("#custom-header").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 4) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9fyvknk/2/)

Or if you like short ternary:

```
$("#custom-header").change(function () {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().length > 4 ? "" : $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: what if user deselect any option? i can't see you are removing that from `selected` when user deselect that.

Comment: if user select all options using mouse click and dragging down it will allow to select all options

Answer (score 2):

Using This code You will get an alert when all option are selected

```
   $('#custom-header').change(function(){
if($("#custom-header > option").length==$("#custom-header    :selected").length){
  alert("The last was clicked.");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But do you know how to reverse the last user click (after the alert)? Or just to block form from sending with all the values checked?

Comment: Yes we can do it by deselect the last selected option-

Answer (score 0):

you can use last-child selector:

```
 var userChoice = $(".test:last-child");
 userChoice.on('click', function() {
         // stuff;
 });
```

It is better if you use onchange event

```
  $('#custom-header').on('change', function() {
       if($(this).selectedIndex == $('#custom-header .test').length)
  });
```

Comment: I don't catch the second solution. Should it work like: if($(this).selectedIndex == $('#custom-header .test').length){ //stuff} ?

Comment: With selectedIndex you obtain the option that is selected, and with test.length you obtain the total options. If you make a comparison selectedIndex - (options.length - 1) you obtain last option